# How can I tell if a network cable has been unplugged?

Tags: c#, networking

I have a C# application that should only be used when the network is down, but am afraid users will just unplug the network cable in order to use it.

Is there a way to detect if the network cable has been unplugged?

Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between network down and cable unplugged? What if I unplug the other end of the cable?

Comment: If the network is down, that is fine. If I could use whatever it is that detects a cable has been unplugged and displays a message saying "A network cable has been unplugged" that would be great.

Comment: The point, I believe, is that there is no difference between the network being down, the cable being unplugged at your end or the cable being unplugged at the other end.

Comment: How are you going to tell the difference between the user unplugging the cable, and, say, the switch dying? Or the cable failing?

Comment: Or a user disabling a network adapter in config screen (I'm usually too lazy to crawl under my desk)

Comment: There are situations when it would be ideal to know that the cable is physically unplugged from the actual device.  For example, in a hospital, a non-electrically-isolated network cable should not be connected to a medical device while operating on a patient.  Thus being able to tell the user they cannot proceed with whatever the operation is while the cable is connected is a good safety feature.

Comment: There's a difference between a NIC being electrically connected to a hub (which itself generates no network traffic), and not being connected. Most NICs have a light to indicate this. I'm sure this is what the questioner was asking to detect. Most times a network goes down it is because some server has stopped responding, not because the electrical connection has gone dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use IsNetworkAlive(). Although technically it doesn't check link state, it's probably better since it can detect wireless and dialup connectivity as well.  Here's an example:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("sensapi.dll")]
    static extern bool IsNetworkAlive(out int flags);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int flags;
        bool connected = IsNetworkAlive(out flags);

    }
}
```

The flags param returns whether the connection is to the internet or just a LAN.  I'm not 100% sure how it knows, but I'd bet it just looks to see if there is a default gateway set.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the closest it is going to get considering all of the ways to work around this.

Answer (score 4):

In my humble opinion, there is no certain way to distinguish between a network down and an unplugged cable. And even if there is a way, there is also a way to work around it.

Let's assume that you have a solution and let's look at some situations:

- There is no network traffic, the cable is not unplugged from the computer: it may be unplugged at the other end.
- There is no network traffic, the cable is unplugged: but this has always been the case, the laptop is connected via Wi-Fi, which is down at the moment.
- There are several network interfaces, only the one connected to WAN is down: should your app work?
- The network is actually down, in the sense you mean: someone has managed to reboot the router continuously for using your app.

Comment: Exactly. So many things can make your network go down manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Answer (score 2):

Some network drivers **are able** to detect this. However you'd need to use unmanaged code to access them from C# (which may be very difficult/impossible) and the solution may not be reliable for all network adapters.

Comment: Interesting... got any links for such H/W, APIs etc ?

Comment: I don't sorry, but I've seen it on major brand NICs such as Intel.

Answer (score 1):

The network card will report this as a state. Tools like `ethtool` can display this (`Link up`), but that is only available for Linux/Unix.

If you can enumerate the installed network cards with a Windows API, I'm sure you'll find the flag for "link up" somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a delegate to the `NetworkChange` Class. When a network change occurs, it doesn't actually notify you what happened, so you could list all the network interfaces (Using `NetworkInterface`), filter the ones that concern you (By checking there properties) and check their operational status.

Answer (score 0):

If I really wanted to use your application and whether it will work depends on something like this, I would always be able to find a way to trick your application. Are you sure there's no better solution?

Comment: I don't think the users of this app would go to the trouble to try and 'trick' it as using it is the quicker option to another program.  The point of this app is for it to only be used when the network is down, which is very rare. I just need a way to ensure that the users will not simply pull out the network cable and use this constantly.  These are not people with a high level knowledge of computers - I just need an indication that they have removed the network cable to give the illusion the network is down.

Answer (score 0):

How about pinging the default gateway?

There is some code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0520__Windows/GetdefaultgatewayfromnetworkkeystoredinRegistry.htm) that gets the default gateway from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To detect 'Is network cable plugged in a machine?', below piece of code works.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isNetworkCableConnected = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
    } 
}
```